# Targeting placeholder text using sass

Tags: html, css, forms, placeholder

So I designed a flat signup form for a website to learn front-end developing. I used Mailchimp for the form, and this all seems to work. Now I have styled up everything how it supposed to be, however I cannot get this placeholder text to have a normal opacity. To me, it seems its opacity is lower than '1', or it does not show up completely 'white'.

I have tried a couple of things, but nothing works; "Opacity 1" and trying to select the placeholder with the vendor fixes mentioned in other posts. I also tried to come up with a mixin to target the vendor fixes (mentioned as a solution in previous posts), but nothing happened.

Thanks!

```css
.newsletter-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form .form-display {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form .form-display .mc-field-group {
  flex: 2;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form .form-display input {
  background: #1d1c1c;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 12px;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form .form-display input[type="submit"] {
  flex: 1;
  border-left: 5px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.newsletter-container .newsletter-form .form-display input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsletter-container">
  <div class="newsletter-form">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="//facebook.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=868cbba0c64a29c8fb08f6aef&amp;id=eda72469b9" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          
          <div class="form-display">
          
            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <label for="mce-FNAME"></label>
              <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
          
            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <label for="mce-EMAIL"></label>
              <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Adress">
            </div>      
            
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
          </div>
          
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>    
      
          <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_868cbba0c64a29c8fb08f6aef_eda72469b9" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct, except you need to specifically change the color of the input placeholder for different browsers, try:

WebKit, Blink (Safari, Google Chrome, Opera 15+) and Microsoft Edge are using a pseudo-element

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
```

Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 are using a pseudo-class: `:-moz-placeholder`

Mozilla Firefox 19+ are using a pseudo-element: `::-moz-placeholder` (double colon)

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 are using a pseudo-class: `:-ms-input-placeholder`.

Browsers <=IE9 & <=Opera12, does not support CSS selectors for placeholders (*no surprise there!*)

```
//affects all input placeholders across webkit browsers
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
//affects all input placeholders across webkit browsers

//no change in any of your other styles
.newsletter-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
//no change in any of your other styles
```

Hope this helped..

**Update:**

This helped the OP.

> Also check if the `::-webkit-input-placeholder` is getting overridden by any other files like `normalize.scss` etc.

Comment: thanks again :), it seems to work when I add all lines in my Codepen. Since I am using SASS to code up this page, it is different to select these pseudo-elements. Now it gets tricky for me, since I am not able to target them correct apparently. Any idea?

Comment: You can just drop them anywhere in your code. pseudo element selectors just does not mean it has to be always attached to an element. If you just write the above code, it should work for all inputs across webkit browsers. No need to prepend or append anything there. Can you also give the link to your Codepen so i can demonstrate

Comment: Yes, it helps when I add it to Codepen however when I add this into my SASS file in my code editor Atom it does not show the white color. Every other change works, but not this one. I have done exactly what you said and somehow it does not seem to work when I run it on Atom.

Comment: It works! My normalize.scss file had a color and opacity defined for the placeholder, therefore it did not override. Thanks again for your help :).

Comment: No worries, you can accept the answer to help others as well. Cheers